# How can I round numbers with three or more digits after the decimal point accurately?

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, calculator

I am in the process of developing a cart system, and encountered some challenges with rounding certain amounts during calculations. Below are the details of my cart.

```
itemPrice = 0.99;
itemQuantity = 10;
totalPrice = 9.90; /* 0.99 * 10 */
```

here I apply 25% of discount coupon on the `totalPrice` amount

```
discountedPrice = 2.475 /* (9.90 * 25) / 100 */
totalPriceAfterDiscount = 7.425 /* 9.90 - 2.475 */
```

Please provide instructions on how to round the `discountedPrice` and `totalPriceAfterDiscount` amounts to two decimal places, ensuring that their sum equals the `totalPrice`.

Upon rounding both figures, the values are as follows: `discountedPrice` = `2.48` and `totalPriceAfterDiscount` = `7.43`. The sum of `2.48` and `7.43` equals `9.91`.

```js
const afterDiscount = Math.round((7.425 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
const discountedAmount = Math.round((2.475 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
const total = afterDiscount + discountedAmount;

console.log(`afterDiscount: ${afterDiscount}`);
console.log(`discountedAmount: ${discountedAmount}`);
console.log(`total: ${total}`);
```

Comment: You can just use subtraction, calculate discountedPrice as you have already done, and then ->   `totalPriceAfterDiscount = totalPrice - discountedPrice`.

Comment: Binary floating-point math (like with JavaScript numbers, and with floating-point numbers in many other languages) is not good for "money math", as it cannot accurately represent familiar decimal fractions and provides no control over rounding mode.

Comment: @Pointy While that's true, even scaling up the numbers will run into problems when you start applying discount percents and tax percents.

Comment: Although that's usually resolved by rounding the discount and/or tax before adding them to the amount.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know enough about number theory, or whatever it is I would need to know, to fully understand what can go wrong when trying to do "proper" base-10 fractional math with base-2 floating point, so I just keep in mind that it doesn't work.

Comment: For exhaustive details see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1):

Rounding financial quantities introduces inaccuracies on the scale of tenths of cents. Just a couple of those will compound into the pennies and beyond.

What most financial systems (all?) do, is to *only round outputs*. Have all intermediate computations take full advantage of the available float precision -- 15 decimal places in JS.

The OP code prematurely rounds several intermediate calculations. By contrast, this code clearly delineates inputs and outputs, and rounds only the output...

```js
// inputs
const itemPrice = 0.99;
const itemQuantity = 10;
const discount = 0.25;

// notice no rounding, and no hard-coded intermediate values
let totalPrice = itemQuantity * itemPrice;
let discountAmount = totalPrice * discount;
let priceAfterDiscount = totalPrice - discountAmount;

// compare unrounded values
console.log("Unrounded totalPrice", totalPrice);
console.log("Unrounded theoretical total", discountAmount + priceAfterDiscount);

console.log("totalPrice appropriate for output", "$" + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: `Rounding financial quantities`,  for banks they even invented there own rounding.  (Bankers rounding).. I suppose those tenths of cents add up to a nice bonus.. :)